# How can I "see" that a map is birational?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, birational-geometry

This came up with the Euler brick.

Let $T=(p,q,r)$ be a Randall triple, i.e. $$(p^2-1)(q^2-1)(r^2-1)=8pqr\ \qquad\text{[eq.1]}.$$ There are tons of maps that map a triple $T$ to another $T'=(p',q',r')$: obvious $$p\mapsto -p,\;q\mapsto 1/q,\;r\mapsto r,$$ still easy $$p\mapsto (p+1)/(p-1),\;q\mapsto (q+1)/(q-1),\;r\mapsto (r+1)/(r-1))$$ and outrageous $$p\mapsto (\dots+p^2q^2r^2)/(\dots+p^2q^2r^2),$$ ($q',r'$ shall be cyclic - I found three such maps).

EDIT: For your convenience, a concrete example is $$p\mapsto -(((-1+q)*(1+p+q+p*q+2*p*r-2*p*q*r-r^2+p*r^2-q*r^2+p*q*r^2))/((1+q)*(1+p-q-p*q+2*r+2*q*r+r^2-p*r^2-q*r^2+p*q*r^2)))$$ which also takes $0,-1,s$ to the Saunderson solution, and also is an identity (so to say! - it's a combination of the easy maps above) on $-p,-q,-r$ (which is *no* allowed map for Eq.1!). Note that the degrees are not maximal here, and don't have to be, thus the $\dots p^2q^2r^2$ notation above.

Thus let $F[p,q,r]$ be a broken rational function of $p,q,r$ (like in the last map example) where the maximum exponent of each variable in numerator and denominator is $2$ (so overall $6/6$), and $p'=F[p,q,r],q'=F[q,r,p],r'=F[r,p,q]$. This makes up for a whopping $54$ free coefficients, so it is hopeless to check if $p',q',r'$ fulfils Eq.1 by plugging it in, do a resultant with Eq.1 to eliminate $r$ and set the coefficients (estimated: up to $p^{100}$) of $p,q$ to zero.

My maps are not only birational, but even involutions. Are there indicators for "F is birational" or "F is even an involution" that help eliminating a bucketload of coefficients first?

The following might help to massacre a few coefficients beforehand: $T=(0,1,s)$ is a valid triple for any $s$, so $F$ must map $T$ either to the other $23$ triples that can be obtained by using the above trivial maps on $T$, or $F$ must give $(p',q',r')=(0/0,0/0,0/0)$ (or another indeterminate) which evaluates to a meaningful limit which is a parametric solution (e.g. the Saunderson one).

Comment: What do you mean by the dots in your "outrageous" map?

Comment: One approach would be to look at their action on the set of solutions mod $p$ for $p$ small but not too small - birational maps should be "close to" permutations.

Comment: does plugging random values of p q and r in (and maybe even reducing mod a huge prime) not help? I’m thinking of Schwartz-Zippel lemma-like statements, but I have no idea about what is computationally feasible etc. (hence: sorry if this is a useless comment!)

Comment: What does "broken" mean (in "broken rational function")?

Comment: @alpoge: That was the first thing I tried, but nonlinear equations in the coefficients are factically worthless. Checking the "singular" solutions at least gives only linear equations in the coefficients. For example, $p^2+q^2=5$ gives a parametric solution, and no map (at least not any with the same nice properties as the one given above) sends this solution to $(0,1,s)$, and *that* I could check by plugging it in and e.g. set $p'=0$ and make a coefficient list of $s$. That computation was quite straightforward and feasible in MATHEMATICA.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Is "broken rational" a false friend of "gebrochen rational" and at least uncommon? Methinks "rational function" is the standard term, now that I googled...

Comment: "broken rational" is certainly uncommon in my experience – more than uncommon, I can't recall ever seeing it. I don't know what "gebrochen rational" means, either. And I've never seen "factically" before.

Comment: I can see that $\,(0,1,s)\,$ and $\,(0,-1,s)\,$ and their permutations are valid triples, but that is only 12 triples. What are the other 12 triples?

Comment: @Somos: $(\infty,1,s)$ :-) (It makes sense to treat infinity as a number here...)

Comment: More precisely with infinity, the Randall triple $(t,x,s),$  $t=\frac{4s}{s^2-1}\big(\frac1{x-1}+\frac12+\frac{1-6s^2+s^4}{16s^2}(x-1)+O(x-1)^2\big)$ is a solution and $\lim_{x\to1}(t,x,s)=(\infty,1,s).\,$